# Naming php function and php class based on your variable name

Tags: php

I have php class and php function that are used together , since im making few of the edits to same files on and off I have to rename my class and function based on the file I am working on so , the code is like this

```
  class myclassName{
       function myfunctionName{
       }
  }
```

and later used as

```
$myvariable = myclassName::myfunctionname($getwhatineed);
```

so I would like to  do this

```
$default_cf_name ="DesiredName";

  class prefix_$default_cf_name{
       function prefix_$default_cf_name{
       }
  }
```

Comment: As a general rule, if you make a change, and then have to apply the same change in multiple files, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand better why I asked ,  I am reusing same class and same functions over and over again and get name clashing , to avoid it  I was thinking of the var naming the functions/classes but this saved me lot of time

http://www.digimantra.com/technology/php/avoid-fatal-error-redeclare-function-php/#comment-258354

a simple

```
if(!function_exists('myfunc')){
}
```

check fixes the issue , same thing with

```
if(!class_exists('myclass')){
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read up on [Object-Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, that looks like a pretty horrible thing to do. You can achieve that at least by [writing the class creation code into a string](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch07_13.htm) and passing it through `eval()` but you  may make a lot of your fellow coders angry with that.

Comment: sorry but using eval() is not an option , the code must be safe and I cannot guarantee since there are more than 5 devs working on the project, but like I advised above simple check helps allot.